# Изменение диапазона чисел

Tags: java, математика

Получаю число в диапазоне от 4 до 66. Хочу трансформировать получаемое число в диапазон от 0 до 100. Подскажите где найти подобное решение? В классе java.lang.Math ответ не нашел.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это считай нормализация числа. 
Сначала находим диапазон

66-4 = 62

И теперь его надо растянуть от 0 до 100, то есть на 100 значений

100/62 = 1.613

Это множитель для числа

Теперь нужно привести числов в координату 0, то есть в нашем случае нужно отнять 4 и диапазон будет от 0 до 62. 
Полученное число умножить на множитель

Пример: число 50

50-4 = 46

46*1.61 = 74.198 - ответ

Тут все еще зависит от того как считать. Если числа целые, то диапазон будет как (макс - мин + 1).

Comment: Ну то есть в общем `new.number = new.low + (old.number - old.low) * (new.high - new.low) / (old.high - old.low)` (кстати, под это дело вполне можно создать свой тип объекта). А вот в случае целых - там всё пакостно. Если считать по тем же формулам - будут провалы на граничных значениях при сжатии диапазона. А при расширении вообще бред будет получаться (часть промежуточных в новом диапазоне не будут получаться никогда).

Comment: Да. Там еще проблемы будут с максимальным числом. Поскольку множитель приходится округлять, то при максимальном числе на выходе будет либо больше, либо меньше допустимого максимума, но никогда неравно. Придется условие добавлять. Вообще, достаточно распространенная задача. Можно подробнее даже описать, если повторов нет

Comment: *Поскольку множитель приходится округлять* Это если считать его отдельно (что на такой задаче вряд ли имеет великий смысл - разве что речь идёт о нормализации такого массива, что весь расчёт занимает часы или дни). Если выполнять весь расчёт единой формулой, то погрешность расчёта будет меньше.

Comment: Если смотреть со стороны математики - то все равно. А в программировании, если Поделить 10 на 3 и я получу "бесконечное" число 3.33333(3). В какой-то момент последние цифры будут отброшены и когда я обратно умножу 3 на него, я получу число близкое к 10, но не 10, что неприятно. Хотя это касается всех целых чисел на выходе. А как бы это исправить я четкого решения не вижу

Comment: Ну как бы обычное дело - погрешности округления для не представимых точно конечных или промежуточных результатов... если совсем прёт - можно задействовать дробную математику, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

```
///
/// \brief ValueMapper функция приведения значения к значению из другого диапазона
/// \param value значение которое надо привести
/// \param smin  диапазон значения минимальный
/// \param smax  диапазон значения максимальный
/// \param dmin  диапазон к которому надо привести значение минимальный
/// \param dmax  диапазон к которому надо привести значение максимальный
/// \return приведенное значение
///
double ValueMapper(double value,double smin,double smax,double dmin, double dmax)
{
    return ((value-smin) / (smax-smin)) * (dmax-dmin) + dmin;
}
```